# How do I update content of an XML tag?

Tags: xml, perl

I want to write a perl code to replace content of a tag in XML. E.g. `<A>Hello<A>`.

I want to search for tag `<A>` in my XML and then replace the value "Hello" with "Hi".

How do I do that?

Comment: Stack  Overflow is here to support programmers who have tried their best but failed but failed to solve a programming problem. There is no evidence here that you have made any effort at all. If you show what code you have written we will do our best to help you with it.

Answer (score 2):

The [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig) module is ideal for this, as it allows you to specify handlers that are executed when a given tag is encountered when parsing XML.

It would help if you had offered some real XML data as an example, but instead I have used a precis of your question.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
  twig_handlers => { A => sub { $_->subs_text(qr/Hello/, 'Hi') } },
);

$twig->parse(*DATA);
$twig->print;

__DATA__
<root>
I want to replace the content of a tag in XML. e.g. In
<A>Hello</A> I want to replace the value "Hello" with "Hi".
</root>
```

**output**

```
<root>
I want to replace the content of a tag in XML. e.g. In
<A>Hi</A> I want to replace the value "Hello" with "Hi".
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML):

```
open file.xml ;
for //A[text()='Hello'] set text() 'Hi' ;
save :b ;
```

Comment: Please elaborate a bit. I am not able to understand the logic.

Comment: @PrafulMathur: The code in this answer is embedded XSH. The author doesn't show the Perl that is necessary to contain it. IMO this module is overkill for such a simple application.

Comment: @Borodin: You can use `xsh` on its own, without any embedding. Suitable for simple applications :-)

Comment: Well yes, except that this was a Perl question and ostensibly a Perl answer :)